# Ajax not posting all data objects

Tags: php, ajax

I am send data by ajax it is posting successfully but not posting all data. like i am posting 185 json objects, but it is posting only 142 objects out of 185.
my code is

```
   $.post( "<?= $this->webroot ?>st/getall", ( data ),function( htmlData )     {

   alert('rgrgr');
   console.log(htmlData);
   $("#submit").prop('disabled', true);
   $("#blank").remove();
   $("#tb tr:first").after(htmlData);
   },'html');
```

Comment: can you provide us with your code?

Comment: Check `post_max_size` in `php.ini` file !!

Comment: it is 64M in php.ini

Comment: Well is your amount of data larger than that?

Comment: I also used 128M in console it shows after 142 objects ... POST data request size limit has been reached by Firebug. ...

Comment: So either you reduce the amount of data, increase the maximum post size, or you post twice. Pick one.

Comment: i cant reduce data. I dont think so that its post size problem.